# Automatically infer second generic argument from first one

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface to define define a column of a table:

```
export interface IColumnDefinition<TRow, TField extends keyof TRow> {
    field: TField;
    label?: string;
    formatter?: (value: TRow[TField], row: TRow) => string;
}
```

Now what I want is to only provide the type of the rows (`TRow`), and let TypeScript automatically infer the type of the field (`TField`) based on the value in the `field` property.

Now assume I have the following interface for my rows:

```
interface User {
    name: string;
    birthDate: number;
}
```

What I tried is the following:

```
const birthDateColumnDefinition: IColumnDefinition<User> = {
    field: 'birthDate',
    formatter: value => new Date(value).toDateString(),
}
```

Which gives me the following error:

> **Generic type 'IColumnDefinition<TRow, TField extends keyof TRow>' requires 2 type argument(s).**

What I also tried is to use a function to create the definition, hoping that the type can be inferred from an argument:

```
function createColumnDefinition<TField extends keyof TRow>(
    field: TField,
    columnDef: Partial<IColumnDefinition<TRow, TField>>): IColumnDefinition<TRow, TField>
{
    return {
        ...columnDef,
        field,
    };
}

const birthDateColumnDefinition = createColumnDefinition<User>('birthDate', {
    formatter: (value, row) => new Date(value).toDateString(),
});
```

This gives me a comparable error:

> **Excepted 2 type arguments, but got 1.**

If however I would also include the row as an argument, and remove all the generic arguments all together, it works fine:

```
function createColumnDefinition<TRow, TField extends keyof TRow>(
    row: TRow,
    field: TField,
    columnDef: Partial<IColumnDefinition<TRow, TField>>): IColumnDefinition<TRow, TField>
{
    return {
        ...columnDef,
        field,
    };
}

const user: User = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    birthDate: 549064800000,
};

const birthDateColumnDefinition = createColumnDefinition(user, 'birthDate', {
    formatter: (value, row) => new Date(value).toDateString(),
});
```

This does work, but this isn't an option since I don't actually have a row when defining the columns.

So is there any way to make this work (preferably by using an interface and not a function)?

Comment: You could replace `TField` with `keyof TRow` in both places, then you only need to supply `TRow`. You would lose the specific type of `row[field]`, though.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to use `TField` in other properties of my column definition. The first parameter of the `formatter` for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Now what I want is to only provide the type of the rows (TRow), and
>   let TypeScript automatically infer the type of the field (TField)
>   based on the value in the field property.

This looks very similar to [partial type inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/23696) which is not currently supported in typescript, and it's not clear if it will ever be supported for this particular use case.

But there is one thing you can do - you can have one function that accepts explicit type parameter for `TRow`, and returns another function that will infer `TField` from its parameter. The syntax is a bit unwieldy, but it works:

```
function columnDefinition<TRow>(): 
   <TField extends keyof TRow>(def: IColumnDefinition<TRow, TField>) => 
        IColumnDefinition<TRow, TField> {
    return  <TField extends keyof TRow>(def: IColumnDefinition<TRow, TField>) => def
}

export interface IColumnDefinition<TRow, TField extends keyof TRow> {
    field: TField;
    label?: string;
    formatter?: (value: TRow[TField], row: TRow) => string;
}

interface User {
    name: string;
    birthDate: number;
}
```

To use it, you call `columnDefinition<User>()` without any parameters, and then immediately call returned function with column definition object as parameter:

```
const birthDateColumnDefinition = columnDefinition<User>()({
    field: 'birthDate',
    formatter: value => new Date(value).toDateString(), 
            // value inferred as (parameter) value: number
});
```

Comment: That's a smart trick, but not really the solution I was hoping for :-) Hopefully TypeScript will support partial type inference some day.

Comment: is there any way to use a wrapper function around `columnDefinition` (maybe `callColumnDefinition`)  that will hide the need to double call columnDefinition? i tried but the type is not getting inferred

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using artem's answer to write a column definition builder class:

```
export class ColumnDefinitionBuilder<TRow> {

  private _columns: Array<IColumnDefinitionWithField<TRow, any>> = [];

  public define<TValue>(field: ((row: TRow) => TValue) | string, def: IColumnDefinition<TRow, TValue>)
    : ColumnDefinitionBuilder<TRow> {
    this._columns.push({...def, field});
    return this;
  }

  public get columns() {
    return this._columns;
  }
}
```

Which allows for the following syntax to define the columns:

```
const userColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionBuilder<User>()
    .define(x => x.birthDate, {
        label: 'Birth date',
        formatter: x => new Date(x).toDateString(),
    })
    .define(x => x.name, {
        label: 'Name',
    })
    .columns;
```