# TypeScript constructor where one generic type is explicit and one is inferred

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Imagine this class to describe a store of objects referenced by a key being one of its attributes:

```
class Store<T, K extends keyof T> {
    readonly key: K;
    readonly items: Map<T[K], T> = new Map();

    constructor(key: K) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    put(item: T) {
        this.items.set(item[this.key], item);
    }

    get(key: T[K]): T | undefined {
      return this.items.get(key);
    }
}
```

To make the example more concrete, let's say we have two types of data we want to keep in `Store`:s:

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    address: string;
}

interface Product {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    category: string;
}

const personStore = new Store<Person, 'name'>('name'); // Stores Persons indexable by their name
const productStore = new Store<Product, 'id'>('id'); // Stores Products indexable by their id

personStore.put({name: 'Homer Simpson', address: '742 Evergreen Terrace'})
const homer = personStore.get('Homer Simpson');

productStore.put({id: 42, name: 'Pizza', category: 'Food'});
const pizza = productStore.get(42);
```

This works, but it bothers me that on creation, `Store`:s must state the attribute used as key twice - once as a type argument and once as a literal value.
Now, type arguments can be inferred from the given argument values, but in this case, `T` is not part of the arguments so it must be stated as a type argument. `K`, however *is* the type of an argument to the constructor so it could be inferred. But it doesn't seem possible to infer `K` while stating `T`?

If I omit the type arguments completely, `T` is inferred to `never`, giving a useless object, and also an error during construction:

```
const someStore = new Store('name'); // Gives "argument of type name is not assignable to never"
```

What I want is to be able to do this:

```
const personStore = new Store<Person>('name'); // T is Person, name is keyof Person.
```

I considered declaring a constructor interface but that doesn't help. Creating a static factory method enables returning a fully typed generic object but also suffers from not being able to specify `T` while inferring K from `key`.

I also obviously don't want to supply a dummy item in the constructor merely to infer `T`.

So: **Is it at all possible to infer one generic type from arguments while stating another? Or is there some clever workaround?**

Comment: Not possible.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51858692/automatically-infer-second-generic-argument-from-first-one

Comment: Workaround https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3ESXACYdQQYY10GIFgQC+BAggA2cPsgDKYLDwA8AFQA0yANLIIAD0ggOGZAGsIATywxkagHz42xHpxxTL5qzW2sSyVw53T2BIcn5kAFk4AAd1AG1tAF0tB2QAXlIIAHco2IAKAEpWZ2QEHEEAVwQlKHyLSx9Cp39-MAALYAwAOgaMr0s-EnFSmMqwfNCIcho1ZsJWkg6u7qnw7owICbX45Z6GlOQ14tKR-0Yt+u87RKTC2eQAH2RK4wgYUAgOFtaeMEqoLg9qswj0LhMGid-GcSHQ4GBgAgyq5IP11PYihlHCpdAYjCYBjY7BiGk0sVlcoplBB1FptCSrCcRlSeN0ECiaegoNgQBjCvkAORkSgCwoEFkQNkclRcnl8wXQKDKUVAA

Comment: The workaround seems to be the best bet, although it requires the static factory method. Thanks.