# Relate a Map's key and value TypeScript types

Tags: typescript, dictionary, generics

I want to relate a `Map`'s key and value in TypeScript. The following doesn't work, but captures what I want:

```
interface ValueTypes {
    a: x;
    b: y;
    c: z;
}

let m = new Map<T extends keyof ValueTypes><T, ValueTypes[T]>();
```

Sadly, I can't seem to parameterise a `Map` before its generic parameters.

There could be other datastructures out there that effectuate equivalent implementations of whatever use-case my `Map` has. That's not what this question is about. It is specifically about TypeScript typing of the generic `Map` type.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your usecase?

Comment: The question is largely supposed to be on TypeScript basics, and hence the code snippet is an MWE, which suffices. An actual use-case would just be this, but with less oversightly type names. For example, `interface CarParts { "engine": Engine; "wheels": Wheels; }`, where the type values are classes, and the map is hence a collection of car parts uniquely indexed by name.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51858692/automatically-infer-second-generic-argument-from-first-one