# Require typing return type but infer argument type

Tags: typescript

So I have a function

```
function asyncMap<T, O>(arr: T[], asyncFn: (t: T) => Promise<O>): Promise<O[]> {
  return Promise.all(arr.map(asyncFn));
}
```

And it needs to be called by specifying both `T` and `O` like

```
asyncMap<string, number>(stringArray, async (singleString) => Number(singleString))
```

What I want though is to infer the type of the array AND the type passed into the callback function (which is a single item of the array) but require specifying the return type.

Something like

```
asyncMap<number>(stringArray, async (singleString) => Number(singleString))
```

The reason why I want to type only the return is that sometimes the callback function can be more complex and Typescript cant infer the type of it resulting in `Promise<...>` instead of a nice type in the IntelliSense.

What does work is typing the function passed in like

```
asyncMap(stringArray, async (singleString): Promise<Number> => Number(singleString))
```

but this first requires typing it as `Promise<>` every time and I would just love to get it that slight bit simpler.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically infer second generic argument from first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51858692/automatically-infer-second-generic-argument-from-first-one)

Comment: @Dimava sadly not as the types don't share any keys or the likes and a helper function would either need to be called first (just personally dislike that) or need to have type arguments which defeats the point as I would basically specify both types again.

Comment: Double call is afaik unavoidable as partial inferrence is unsupported atm (see link). You can make that `f(a).g<T>(b)` but that's basically all you can