# Type inference between two generics with a union

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I have the following type for a react component using react-hook-form

```
import {
  type FieldPath,
  type FieldValues,
  type FieldPathValue,
} from "react-hook-form";

interface FormControlRadioBoxProps<
    TFieldValues extends FieldValues, 
    TFieldPath extends FieldPath<TFieldValues> = FieldPath<TFieldValues>, 
    > extends ComponentProps<typeof RadioBox> {
  name: TFieldPath;
  options: {
    name: string;
    value: FieldPathValue<TFieldValues, TFieldPath>;
  }[];
}
```

Given the following component usage I do have type hinted top level name attribute, but I do not have the `options[].value`, which I would assume would be inferred from the top level name, as they share `TFieldPath` type.

```
const TypedRadioBox = HookRadioBox<z.infer<typeof validator>>;

// info.agreement is of type 'yes'|'no'

function ComponentInsideMyForm() {
  return <TypedRadioBox
          label='Do you agree?'
          name='info.agreement'
          options={[
            {
              name: 'I do',
              value: 'yes', // This is resolving to all possible types for the form
            },
            {
              name: 'I do not',
              value: 'no', // This is resolving to all possible types for the form
            },
          ]}
        />
}
```

I think this is caused by TFieldPath being actually a union of all possible paths which for some reason does **not** get **narrowed** by me specifying `info.agreement`, which then in turn creates all possible values for the value property. But how do I stop this from happening and only use the actual literal name passed as a prop to the component?

I want to keep type hinting for the name and get type hinting for the `value` property based on it's name.

### EDIT: Reproduction demo

Link for the demo is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3gKDnAYsFAGwBMAFAQxgAsAabPAki6gNXMIFcU6d8ji2nFAGc6AXzgAzKBBBwARFBTkAxjAC0VCBADW6ydBDyA3JkxJUeQwBFK5OAF4M9YADsDALmc4cr8iBQvYRgoNwBzehxhDig-AKCQ8Mi4cjClFADXGC95RBF5OAAfBVcIAuL5EHJEACMUeXoxHjgQCFcURC8sHzg3FVlAuFcOEDqoZJQAD1RXYREvYdGUcZwxTDXMNxhlyVU0XEMAYTaQiEIASVcwDhhSGTBhAB56ABU+EkEuYTgp7ddib7vATsL7NN6MMiUKg-SZ-AEMfjMKiPcH8T4iAB8jgRTChKKB6OEGLoWO6Q38g1RuOophwxBQuw4hBg6K8QKR6PxEMJNDgVMh1Axpg2AHoRXAABIAUQASlK4OcAMp86VwUgygDyACEADJSgCyAEEXudDmrDTKXmZ+rN4MQ7NYMhA2UcTjILlcbncIA9HgcoCBbDByFinGS4oN5G4DAA6VLpTIweTNemM5mshQFMV4c4ADX1Uq8EuWaAA7mgqOQAG5odiEOCQYTCYA1QhoKsgkRSGRyf2Buy88jfahoflI3rfUrwPxQGTl4hwGqIOAAAwjK7gpaoKFccA4cwXbgQ27gqfITJZ57b6zMZiAA). I have narrowed it to use only typescript without react, but with the types from react-hook-form.

> NOTE: I have noticed that the same is happening in the `<Controller/>` component in react hook form, where they actually use the same thing as in the minimal reproduction that I have provided wit the `defaultValue` being type hinted and broken the same way by the `name` value

```
import type {
  FieldPath,
  FieldPathValue,
  FieldValues,
} from "react-hook-form";

type FormData = {
  info: {
    name: string
    surname: string
    agreement: "yes" | "no" | "maybe"
  },
  money: {
    income: number
    expenses: number
  }
}

interface FormControlInputProps<
  TFieldValues extends FieldValues,
  TFieldPath extends FieldPath<TFieldValues> = FieldPath<TFieldValues>,
> {
  name: TFieldPath;
  defaultValue: FieldPathValue<TFieldValues, TFieldPath>;
}

// HERE IS THE PROBLEMATIC PART

const dataDemo: FormControlInputProps<FormData> = {
  name: "info.agreement",
  defaultValue: "" // FIXME: Here we have all possible values from FormData, as the TFieldPath is not narrowed by `name` when used in the defaultVaule. If we leave only the info.agreement in the FormData, then we have type hinting
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77547282/edit) the question to include a [mre] that doesn't include errors which are unrelated to the described issue? [Here's a link to a TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/mbyqbN) into which I copied and pasted your code. As you can see in the playground, there are some errors related to missing information in the code (e.g. `ComponentProps`, `RadioBox`, `HookRadioBox`, `z`, `validator`). After those errors are no longer present, perhaps we can focus directly on the problem that you described.

Comment: @jsejcksn I have provided the demo with additional description. Is this enough or do you need anything more?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77547282/type-inference-between-two-generics-with-a-union?noredirect=1#comment136776061_77547282) @Device 
 It looks like there aren't any more reference error diagnostics (and that you might have already received your answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TypeScript you need to either provide all type parameters (either explicitly or as default value in signature) or none.

If none is provided, then TS will try to infer type parameter from value:

```
type Test<T> = {test: T};
const myFunc = <T,>(arg: Test<T>): T => arg.test;
myFunc({test: 10});
// ^ here TS can infer that T is number
```

So, in your code you have both type parameters specified: one explicitly (`FormData`) and another one as default parameter (`FieldPath<TFieldValues>`). `FieldPath<TFieldValues>` is union which contains all possible paths for your form. And since `"info.agreement"` is a member of that union, TS doesn't show any errors: type parameter is provided (via default value) and provided value satisfies that type, so all is fine. But since type parameter isn't narrowed, it also accepts all possible values for `defaultValue`.

What could solve this problem is partial type inference, but it's not yet in TypeScript ([related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51858692/automatically-infer-second-generic-argument-from-first-one)).

Kind of workaround is to use two nested functions: to one your provide required type parameter, and in next one you let TS infer it from usage:

```
interface FormControlInputProps<
  TFieldValues extends FieldValues,
  TFieldPath extends FieldPath<TFieldValues>,
> {
  name: TFieldPath;
  defaultValue: FieldPathValue<TFieldValues, TFieldPath>;
}

const wrapper = <TFieldValues extends FieldValues>() => <TFieldPath extends FieldPath<TFieldValues>>(val: FormControlInputProps<TFieldValues, TFieldPath>) => {
  return val;
}

// This fails with useful error message
wrapper<FormData>()({
  name: "info.agreement",
  defaultValue: "not gonna work lol",
});

// This works
wrapper<FormData>()({
  name: "info.agreement",
  defaultValue: "maybe",
});
```

I'm not very familiar with `react-hook-form`, but looking at your original code it seems that you create separate RadioBox component for each form. So in your case you can incorporate mentioned workaround like this:

```
const createTypedRadioBox = <TFieldValues extends FieldValues>() => {

  // This is your RadioBox implementation
  return <TFieldPath extends FieldPath<TFieldValues>>(props: FormControlInputProps<TFieldValues, TFieldPath>) => {
    return <div>
      {/* ... */}
    </div>;
  }
}

const MyTypedRadioBox = createTypedRadioBox<FormData>();

<MyTypedRadioBox 
  name="info.agreement"
  defaultValue="maybe"
/>
```

[TS playground with complete code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3gKDnAYsFAGwBMAFAQxgAsAabPAki6gNXMIFcU6d8ji2nFAGc6AXzgAzKBBBwARFBTkAxjAC0VCBADW6ydBDyA3JkxJUeQwBFK5OAF4M9YADsDALmc4cr8iBQvYRgoNwBzehxhDig-AKCQ8Mi4cjClFADXGC95RBF5OAAfBVcIAuL5EHJEACMUeXoxHjgQCFcURC8sHzg3FVlAuFcOEDqoZJQAD1RXYREvYdGUcZwxTDXMNxhlyVU0XEMAYTaQiEIASVcwDhhSGTBhAB56ABU+EkEuYTgp7ddib7vATsL7NN6MMiUKg-SZ-AEMfjMKiPcH8T4iAB8dAx3iG-kGqKYUNMOGIKF2HEIMHRXiBSPRKKB6NEcEJkOoGNMG36s3gAHcoOQwKgoI44IyIcyYXDAZKQZiABQASkcOIliKh0pQ-1lGuo6o+8uEGIxCoAbuxaUcTjILlcbncIA8DcChCy2UiMSqHDjunAlDAYq44BbCFyzAKhSLHgcoCBbDByKalQq-XFBvI3AYAHSpdKZGDyZpkilUmklCDwMJtPxwPnQHRwQhnIvrJWmTCR4XLGM2OzJ1P0dM5LMQXNpFAZbWF4vk8iU6nynJVWr1cTtsyYHnBOAqJSUFAvZAoYgAJXIxGAEAAQhBJmKXVLftr4UyjcnVc56AB6b+sqjAN8gFwIgEAxHA56Xjed69OAhBTlklBXq49ABkG4oepqz46giRL6myzImgqYD3MIVpxscWS2pc1y3KRj5GjQrJ0lCXqfn6OBobE4qXmaGLJDg6DfgAVHA2biXAwnfmsPSPN+vGco06xmNu8AALKIEeqBnheV63veTh7so2xaSekF6XevZxgmSbKh2qm7tAShqOZ0EGXACqPBppk6VB+lwEO+IOJm7hjnmk4Fg0pJzgu6LBSudQNN+Xr2W0O7LDIUCuf5Tied5x6+RZ96BQEwWjuO+bTlFcAlvOZbysFGXQElKWbkAA)

Comment: This actually might be exactly what i was looking for, to aid our need for us currently, i have seen the partial inference thread even on github and hoped someone would at lesst find a workaround :). Later today I will try what you sugested and give you feedback 

Comment: Hey, did you try it? How did it go?